# Is there a documented process in 'Jamming' an NXT Ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, building

Just trying to gather a bit of information for a competition between a few other NXT builds, I was wondering if there was a way to make the ultrasonic sensor completely useless for the competition as I'm sure it would put a new spin to my opponents.

Comment: Isn't that... *cheating*?

Answer (score 3):

Since everything is fair in love and war, you could do this:

Using an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) and this [NXT compatible shield](http://shop.tkjelectronics.dk/product_info.php?products_id=29), you could program it to send a continuous burst at 11494,253Hz creating noise in the frequency range of the NXT Ultrasonic sensor.

[image]

[This site](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2011/10/nxt-shield-ver2/) shows how to use the Shield with the sensor.  All you have to do is modify the code to create a long burst instead of a controlled ping.

Comment: Depending on the contest, non-LEGO material might be explicitly excluded - unless you hide it in your pocket or something.

Comment: Assuming of course that it is an accepted countermeasure in that competition. :)